# Execute a function when an object's property changes

Tags: c#, .net

I have an object model that looks like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<MyOtherObject> TheListOfOtherObjects { get; set; }

    public List<int> MyOtherObjectIDs { get; set; }

    public void GetListOfMyOtherObjectIDs() 
    {
       // function that extracts the IDs of objects in
       // the list and assigns it to MyOtherObjectIDs
    }
}
```

At the moment, I've got some code that executes `GetListOfMyOtherObjectIDs` when `TheListOfOtherObjects` gets populated from a query. Now I've got another place in the code that populates this list as well and when it does, it also needs to execute the `GetListOfMyOtherObjectIDs` function.

Is there a way to make this process automatic so that when `TheListOfOtherObjects` is popuplated, regardless of which code triggers it, the object model will automatically execute `GetListOfMyOtherObjectIDs`?

Comment: What is the return type of the method? Its current signature looks like a constructor not being it actually.

Comment: @abatishchev: sorry, forgot the return type; it's void.

Comment: Have you searched and read about `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ObservableCollection<T>`? You definitely need to, it will solve your issue.

Comment: No, I don't know how to do this, which is why I'm asking how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use you own `set` accessor:

```
public class MyModel
{
    private List<MyOtherObject> _TheListOfOtherObjects;
    public List<MyOtherObject> TheListOfOtherObjects {
        get { return _TheListOfOtherObjects; }
        set { _TheListOfOtherObjects = value; GetListOfMyOtherObjectIDs(); }
    }

    public List<int> MyOtherObjectIDs { get; set; }

    public void GetListOfMyOtherObjectIDs() 
    {
       // function that extracts the IDs of objects in
       // the list and assigns it to MyOtherObjectIDs
    }
}
```

Comment: ah ok!!!!! What does this mean: set { _TheListOfOtherObjects = value; ?? If I remove it and leave just set { GetListOfMyOtherIvjectIDs(); } will it work? Can I avoid the private List<MyOtherObject> property too?

Comment: +1 I'd suggest a `private set` on `MyOtherObjectIDs` if it's to be fully managed via `TheListOfOtherObjects` set method.

Comment: @frenchie You may like to read about [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) (the one you used in OP) and [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) (the one I used)

Comment: The only danger with this is that someone can add/remove from `TheListOfOtherObjects` and `GetListOfMyOtherObjectIDs` wouldn't be called, leaving the two lists out of sync.

Comment: @mikez I think they will both be referencing to the same object so that they are basically identical in content. But you're right, this doesn't handle when some code add/remove from the `List`. Thinking of a custom wrapper class...